# Python Pycharm: Plot gets Coarse When Zoomed in

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Using Pycharm and Matplotlib e.g. with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_random = np.random.random(5)
plt.plot(my_random)
plt.show()
```

gives easily a plot, that appears in Pycharm Professional Edition 2017.3 (Ubuntu 14.04) in the SciView window:
[image: default view]

If I zoom in to the plot, it gets very coarse and I cannot analyse details anymore:

[image: coarse in details]

Is it possible to have this plot as a vector plot, so that details are maintained when zooming in?

Or can I plot in a more "native" (in the sense of closer to matplotlib, as this plot seems Pycharm specific) way, so that zooming is done in a vectorized and not bitmap way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about pycharm.

But you should try increasing the DPI of the figure (and avoid relying on the `pyplot` API's state machine):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
fig = pyplot.figure(dpi=120)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2], 'ko')
```

Explicitly creating the [figure](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) will give you much more control in the long run.

Note the the display DPI of the figure isn't necessarily the resolution it will be saved at:

```
fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=600, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Currently zooming in with adaptive resolution is not supported.**

Your best option is to use a different tool for that.

**To cancel the sciview:**
settings -> Tools -> python scientific -> untick "show plots in tool window"

view -> untick "scientific mode".

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `show()`, consider using `savefig('plot.pdf')`, which supports zooming as you desire.

EDIT: What I mean by that suggestion is to run the following program, which replaces final line of the OP code.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.6

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

my_random = np.random.random(5)
plt.plot(my_random)
plt.savefig('plot.pdf')
```

Running it on MacOS produces a little more than half a dozen KiB of output that Preview.app shows nicely. This comes from one sample run:

```
$ ./plot.py && wc -c plot.pdf && conda list --export | grep plot
    7187 plot.pdf
matplotlib=2.1.1=py36h2fb3e9e_0
```

Comment: just executing `plt.savefig("plot.pdf")` generates an empty pdf file.